# VS 2015 - Toolbox not shows UserControl

Tags: visual-studio-2015, user-controls, toolbox

I downloaded today Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and created a new C# Windows-Forms Application. I created a new UserControl.

After Rebuilding the UserControl is not showing in the toolbox.

I tried the same in Visual Studio 2012, here is all ok.

Google said i shall check Tools->Options->Windows-Form-Designer, but there is no Tools. I find a Option Windows-Form-Designer under Extrals->Option->Windows-Form-Designer but there is no option about the toolbox.

What can i do?

Answer (score -2):

To show the Toolbox, click on "View ➔ Toolbox", or press Ctrl+Alt+X.

To add controls, right-click inside the box, click on "Choose Items", and add the items you need from the appropriate tab.

Comment: Question is "why user control is not showing up in the toolbox"